# How do I remove every value from a vector?

Tags: r

```
for(val in eveni){
y <- paste(xi,"A",x)
xi <- c(xi,y)
x=x+1
}
```

I want to empty the vector "y". How do I do that?
Thank You.

Comment: by deleting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand why you would do that, but you could do:

```
name_of_your_vector <- c()
```

to make it empty.

Or

```
name_of_your_vector <- numeric(NA, length(name_of_your_vector))
```

to make all its values NA

Comment: Thank You! you are so fast! I am new to R so I am just doing stuff.